# Как скрыть/отобразить элемент в контейнере при ресайзе контейнера?

Tags: javascript

Есть родительский контейнер с двумя элементами. При уменьшении величины контейнера (при ресайзе) необходимо скрыть первый элемент? когда не хватает места (соприкасаются). При расширении контейнера, когда достаточно место, необходимо отобразить сркытый первый элемент.
Необходимо исключить эффект мерацания (появления и исчезнования элемента) при ресайзе.
Ниже функция, в которая скрывает первый эелемент. Не могу добиться отображение этого элемента при увеличении контейнера.

```js
function refresh() {
  const elements =  document.querySelector('.parent').children
    const firstElem = elements[0]
    const secondElem = elements[1]
    const minSize = 10
    const distance = secondElem.offsetLeft - (firstElem.offsetLeft + firstElem.offsetWidth)
    let oldDistance = distance
    let direction = oldDistance >= distance


    console.log('distance:', distance)
    console.log('direction:', direction)
    console.log('oldDistance:', oldDistance)
    console.log('firstElem.clientWidth:', firstElem.clientWidth)


    if (direction) {
      console.log('--')
      if (distance <= minSize) {
        firstElem.style.position = 'absolute'
        firstElem.style.opacity = '0'
      }
    } else {
      console.log('+')
      if (distance >= firstElem.clientWidth + minSize) {
        firstElem.style.position = ''
        firstElem.style.opacity = '1'
      }
   }
}

window.addEventListener('resize', refresh)
```

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.parent div {
  padding: 5px;
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.parent div:last-child {
  width: 300px
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>child 1</div>
  <div>child 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Привет! Ты пробовал эту задачу выполнить с помощью [CSS @media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) ?

Comment: Привет. Не годится стилями. Это фрагмент верстки, который будет использоваться в разных частях страницы и не должен привязываться к рмеру вьюпорта. Нужно отталкивать от ширины контейнера, который может сужаться вручную. Не знаю смог ли объяснить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изменил ваш код и добавил несколько правил, для управления отображения дочерних элементов в зависимости от размера экрана.

```js
function refresh() {
    const parent = document.querySelector('.parent');
    const children = parent.querySelectorAll('.child');
    const minSize = 10;

    const totalWidth = parent.offsetWidth;
    const firstChildWidth = children[0].offsetWidth;
    const secondChildWidth = children[1].offsetWidth;

    if (totalWidth < firstChildWidth + secondChildWidth + minSize) {
        children[0].classList.add('hidden'); 
    } else {
        children[0].classList.remove('hidden'); 
    }
}

window.addEventListener('resize', refresh);
refresh();
```

```css
.parent {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: relative; 
}

.child {
    padding: 5px;
    background: yellow;
    border: 1px solid red;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease, left 0.5s ease;
    left: 0;
    position: relative; 
}

.child.hidden {
    opacity: 0; 
    left: -100%; 
    position: absolute; 
}

.child:nth-child(1) {
    width: 300px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

.child:nth-child(2) {
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">child 1</div>
    <div class="child">child 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да. Код решает задачу частично. Из-за того что резко освобождается место при скрытии элемента, то возникает эффект его мерцания, когда он скрывается и сразу появляется при ресайзе. Это как раз хотел пофиксить

Comment: Согласен с тобой, первый элемент скрывался очень резко, в связи с этим исправил код который ранее выложил. Теперь первый элемент скрываеться плавно.

Comment: Спасибо. То что надо.

Comment: Рад был помочь! )))